# Use Axios defaults in laravel vapor signed-storage-url

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-vapor

Using Tymon jwt tokens for auth. Laravel works fine.

When using the upload to S3 code for Laravel vapor I cannot get the signed-storage-url to use my axios defaults:

`axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token;`

Store Method as shown in the docs:

```
Vapor.store(this.$refs.file.files[0], {
    progress: progress => {
        this.uploadProgress = Math.round(progress * 100);
    }
}).then(response => {
...
```

It calls this in the index.js of the npm package:

```
async store(file, options = null) {
        // want this to use my default header.
        const response = await axios.post('/vapor/signed-storage-url', {
            'bucket': options.bucket || '',
            'content_type': options.contentType || file.type,
            'expires': options.expires || ''
        });
```

Maybe something to do with the npm module not being in the correct scope.

I have overridden the vapor-core signed-storage-url controller to use the token and can get that to work no problem with Postman.
It is calling Vapor.store that doesn't add the token to the axios call and I don't see a way to pass in the headers.

**Edit**: You can use these packages without signing up for Vapor.

```
composer require laravel/vapor-core
```

and

```
npm install --save-dev laravel-vapor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLVED**
So to make this work I copied the async store method to my vue component methods and called it from there. Gets the default headers but ...

That created an axios header issue with S3 which is solved by doing this:

```
async store(file, options = null) {
            const response = await axios.post('/vapor/signed-storage-url', {
                'bucket': options.bucket || '',
                'content_type': options.contentType || file.type,
                'expires': options.expires || ''
            });

            if (typeof options.progress === 'undefined') {
                options.progress = () => {};
            }
// This is the fix for the headers. Instance just for the S3 PUT
            var instance = axios.create();
            instance.defaults.headers.common = {};
            const s3Response = await instance.put(response.data.url, file, {
                headers: response.data.headers,
                onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                    options.progress(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
                }
            });

            response.data.extension = file.name.split('.').pop()

            return response.data;
        },
```

Thanks to https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/382#issuecomment-254712154

Comment: Why does this need to be under an authenticated route anyway?

Comment: @AliGajani So my S3 bucket is not available to all. Only logged in users can upload images.

Comment: Did you have to define `vapor/signed-storage-url` or it is pre-installed?

Comment: The signed-storage-url is part of vapor-core. I needed to overide it so I could set the uploads as public read. 
 app/overrides/src/Controllers/SignedStorageUrlController.php

Comment: Vapor-core was updated to set visibility.see this commit https://github.com/laravel/vapor-core/commit/d9cf84f19835df51f64483e7ce49e5b04da1d146#diff-2b0e794964ec76866c75e3a1f408569a

Comment: This is indeed the solution for Tymon JWT with Vapor. Saved my day, nice work.